# apache dolphinscheduler--ApiExceptionHandler:41 - null org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

When I try to create 'SQL' task in process,got error like in next log. but create 'shell or spark' task is normal. and also is normal when create 'sql' task in another server with the same configuration.

```
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:34.393 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.LoginController:84 - login user name: admin 
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:34.457 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.security.PasswordAuthenticator:59 - sessionId : ad15ef0a-b1c0-448d-858e-b25c948390ec
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:35.738 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.UsersController:299 - login user admin,get user info
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:35.942 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.TenantController:112 - login user admin, list paging, pageNo: 1, searchVal: , pageSize: 10
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:37.231 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.QueueController:68 - login user admin, query queue list
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:48.835 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.TenantController:216 - login user admin, verfiy tenant code: JM
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:48.851 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.TenantController:83 - login user admin, create tenant, tenantCode: JM, tenantName: 作业管理员, queueId: 1, desc: 
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:49.666 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.TenantController:112 - login user admin, list paging, pageNo: 1, searchVal: , pageSize: 10
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:55.561 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.UsersController:116 - login user admin, list user paging, pageNo: 1, searchVal: , pageSize: 10
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:57.162 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.TenantController:135 - login user admin, query tenant list
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:57.163 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.QueueController:68 - login user admin, query queue list
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:58.269 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.UsersController:162 - login user admin, updateProcessInstance user, userName: admin, email: xxx@qq.com, tenantId: 1, userPassword: ******, phone: , user queue: default
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:52:58.405 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.UsersController:116 - login user admin, list user paging, pageNo: 1, searchVal: , pageSize: 10
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:25.638 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.DataSourceController:281 - login user admin, connect datasource: apiconf, note: , type: MYSQL, connectType: null, other: 
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:27.130 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.DataSourceController:361 - login user admin, verfiy datasource name: apiconf
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:27.146 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.DataSourceController:101 - login user admin create datasource name: apiconf, note: , type: MYSQL, host: 192.168.6.16, port: 3306, database : apiconf, principal: , userName : tcc, connectType: null, other: 
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:29.371 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ProjectController:157 - login user admin, query project list paging
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:35.304 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ProjectController:79 - login user admin, create project name: 测试, desc: 
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:35.423 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ProjectController:157 - login user admin, query project list paging
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:36.900 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.DataAnalysisController:104 - count process instance state, user:admin, start date: 2021-09-27 00:00:00, end date:2021-09-27 14:32:51, project id:1
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:36.900 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.DataAnalysisController:76 - count task state, user:admin, start date: 2021-09-27 00:00:00, end date:2021-09-27 14:32:51, project id 1
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:36.901 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.DataAnalysisController:126 - count process definition , user:admin, project id:1
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:37.927 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ProcessDefinitionController:290 - query process definition list paging, login user:admin, project name:测试
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:38.911 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ResourcesController:293 - query resource list, login user:admin, resource type:, program type:{}
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:38.913 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ProjectController:264 - login user admin, query all project list
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:38.916 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ProcessDefinitionController:257 - query process definition list, login user:admin, project name:测试
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:38.922 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.WorkerGroupController:135 - query all worker group: login user admin
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:38.959 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ResourcesController:293 - query resource list, login user:admin, resource type:PYTHON, program type:{}
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:38.980 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ResourcesController:177 - query resource list, login user:admin, resource type:FILE
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:53:38.983 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.TenantController:135 - login user admin, query tenant list
    INFO 2021-09-27 22:54:01.499 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.controller.ProcessDefinitionController:139 - verify process definition name unique, user:admin, project name:测试, process definition name:s
    ERROR 2021-09-27 22:54:01.553 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.api.exceptions.ApiExceptionHandler:41 - null
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:422)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:277)

can anyone help me?
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk the stack and understand who is calling printStackTrace() (or logging) for that exception.
Since it's a Jetty exception that implement Jetty's QuietException, Jetty logs it at DEBUG level and you should not see it the logs unless configured so.

Btw, it is important to provide a clear contextual environment.